# Docker compose MongoDB with NodeJS using yarn

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use docker compose to put in containers a node.js server and a mongodb database. I'm also trying to use yarn as my package-manager. My project is codded in typescript and my Mongodb is used as a service for my server.

For what I have at the moment, it works just fine, but I'm not sure if my implementation is even good. When I run `docker-compose up`, the containers and the images of node.js and mongodb are created, and the containers are running on the specified ports.

The problem is that when I kill the mongodb container, my nodejs server still has access to the database, like if my container mongodb container is still running. I would guess that it's because my mongodb server is also running on the same container as my node.js server.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

ADD package.json /app/package.json
ADD yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock

WORKDIR /app

# Installing packages
RUN yarn

ADD . /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Building TypeScript files
RUN yarn build

CMD ["node", "./dist/app.js"]
```

These are the scripts in my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.ts",
    "format": "eslint src/**/*.ts --fix",
    "start": "tsc && node --unhandled-rejections=strict ./dist/app.js",
    "debug": "export DEBUG=* && npm run start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "ts-node src/app.ts",
    "build": "rm -rf build && tsc -p ."
  },
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    environment:
        - COSMOSDB_HOST=${COSMOSDB_HOST}
        - COSMOSDB_PORT=${COSMOSDB_PORT}
        - COSMOSDB_DBNAME=${COSMOSDB_DBNAME}
        - COSMOSDB_USER=${COSMOSDB_USER}
        - COSMOSDB_PASSWORD=${COSMOSDB_PASSWORD} 
    ports: 
      - "4000:4000" 
    links: 
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
```

I don't seem to understand what's wrong with my files...
Can you help me ? Also, would you have some recommendation to give me to optimize the build or anything else ? Thank you !

Comment: So how do you kill your mongodb container? `docker-compose down` in the same directory?  You can see all running container with `docker ps`

Comment: `docker container list`, I retrieve the Id of my mongo container, and I enter `docker container kill <mongo-id>`

Comment: Well, you simply don't connect to a stopped or removed container, so either it isn't stopped, or you are mistaken it for something else, like your cloud database. (Try pulling he ethernet plug, that should be a sure way to check that theory).

Comment: what do you set `COSMOSDB_HOST` to?

Comment: COSMOSDB_HOST is a variable that I set to connect to my azure cosmos db.